# Get all elements in list until its end or another argument Python

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a command that takes few **non**-positional arguments for example

> send_dm -u def750 -n 15 -msg Hello world!

It takes whole list and indexes arguments

```
('-u', 'def750', '-n', '1', '-msg', 'Hello', 'world!')
def750 1 "Hello
```

Using this code:

```
allowed_args = ["-u", "-n", "-msg"]    
index = args.index("-u") + 1
u = str(args[index])
index = args.index("-n") + 1
n = str(args[index])
index = args.index("-msg") + 1
msg = str(args[index])
```

I need to take -msg argument from its start to

1. Start of new argument
2. End of argument list

So if I do something like this

> send_dm -msg Hello world! -u def750 -n 15

I'll still get:
def750 1 Hello World!

Right now only thing I'm getting is first element after -msg argument and I have no idea how to do it

Comment: Are you using argparse?

Comment: You could try writing some code to loop through the remaining args once you find 'msg'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try looking for the `-` at the beginning of each parameter

```py
allowed_args = ["-u", "-n", "-msg"]
argumentDict = {
    "-u": "",
    "-n": "",
    "-msg": ""
}

currentArgument = ""
for argument in args:
    if argument.startswith("-"):
        if argument not in allowed_args:
            return # wrong argument given
        currentArgument = argument
    else:
        if argumentDict[currentArgument] != "": # add space when already something given
            argumentDict[currentArgument] += " "
        argumentDict[currentArgument] += argument
```

You can then access your parameters via

```py
argumentDict["-u"]
argumentDict["-n"]
argumentDict["-msg"]
```

---

The output of

```py
print(argumentDict)
```

Would be

```py
{'-u': 'def750', '-n': '1', '-msg': 'Hello world!'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is something you are looking for, but you could try:

```
inp = ('-u', 'def750', '-n', '1', '-msg', 'Hello', 'world!')
allowed_args = ["-u", "-n", "-msg"] 
dic = {}
current_key = None
for el in inp:
    if el in allowed_args:
        current_key = el
        dic[current_key] = []
    else:
        dic[current_key].append(el)
    
for key, val in dic.items():
    dic[key] = " ".join(val)

print(dic)
```

**output:**

```
{'-msg': 'Hello world!', '-n': '1', '-u': 'def750'}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to this. One way would be to loop over the arguments and append the arguments based on the state of a flag, although this would be quite verbose.

Another way would be to use `itertools.groupby` to group subsequent elements based on whether they start with '-', and filter out the dash-prefixed entries using `itertools.filterfalse`:

```
import itertools as it

DASH = '-'

args = ('-u', 'def750', '-n', '1', '-msg', 'Hello', 'world!')

parsedargs = it.filterfalse(lambda x: x[0],
                    it.groupby(args,
                        lambda y: y.startswith(DASH)))
```

Or; putting it in a dictionary right away and also filtering out disallowed arguments:

```
import itertools as it

DASH = '-'
allowed_args = ('-u','-n','-msg')
args = ('-u', 'def750', '-n', '1', '-msg', 'Hello', 'world!',
        '-not-allowed', 'asdf', 'qwerty')

argdict = {
    k: list(v[1])
    for k, v in zip(
        [entry for entry in args if entry.startswith(DASH)],
        it.filterfalse(lambda x: x[0],
                       it.groupby(args,
                                  lambda y: y.startswith(DASH)))
        )
    if k in allowed_args
   }

print(argdict)
```

Resulting in:

```
{'-u': ['def750'], '-n': ['1'], '-msg': ['Hello', 'world!']}
```

But is not very readable..

Or perhaps more simple, extensible, and readable; use `argparse` from the standard library, as it was built for this purpose and offers more funtionality. There are also third party libraries out there which allow easily building a CLI for you program.